# Make walking leap character

Tags: controller, leap-motion, unreal-engine4

I've got issues working with leap motion.

I want to make a walking leap character so I add a leap motions controller actor in my character viewport but when I make character move (with add movement input blueprint block) the hands don't follow the character...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you parent the controller actor correctly. However, we are currently recommend that people use the https://github.com/getnamo/leap-ue4 plugin instead.